# symbolic links and htaccess on apache2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

We have a ubuntu machine on ec2 as a server, and the default `/var/www/html` has a sym link to `/home/ubuntu`

```
ubuntu@ip-172-XX-XX-XXX:/var/www/html$ ls -al
total 20
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root  4096 Sep 10 02:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Sep 10 02:17 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11321 Sep 10 02:17 index.html
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    20 Sep 10 02:19 website -> /home/ubuntu/website
```

The directory `/home/ubuntu/website` contains

```
public_html/app/
```

which is the home (base) for CodeIgniter. When I access the website as

```
http://ec2-34-XXX-XX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com/website/public_html/app/index.php/login
```

I can see the page loaded correctly. But when I access it as

```
http://ec2-34-XXX-XX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com/website/public_html/app/login
```

I can't - It shows

```
Not Found

The requested URL /website/public_html/app/login was not found on this server.
```

The .htaccess file is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /website/public_html/app/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/public_html/app/index.php/$1 [L]
```

What am I missing here ? (Mod Rewrite is enabled.)

Comment: The .htaccess file is in `/website/public_html/app/`?

Comment: Yes, thanks the issue is now resolved !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/public_html/app/index.php/$1 [L]
```

I think that RewriteBase is the problem as it duplicates the rule in RewriteRule

Answer (score 0):

There were two problems:

1. As @the-agony has mentioned above, RewriteBase was likely duplicating the rule, so switched to this:

   `RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/public_html/app/index.php/$1 [L]`
2. Moreover checking the log by

   `sudo tail /var/log/apache2/error.log`

showed:

```
    [Wed Oct 11 19:41:36.396178 2017] [core:alert] [pid 30110] [client 130.245.192.0:27286] /var/www/html/website/public_html/.htaccess: Expected </IfModule> before end of configuration
    [Wed Oct 11 19:44:11.269472 2017] [core:alert] [pid 30106] [client 130.245.192.0:13926] /var/www/html/website/public_html/.htaccess: Expected </IfModule> before end of configuration
    [Wed Oct 11 19:44:14.046920 2017] [core:alert] [pid 30108] [client 130.245.192.0:22481] /var/www/html/website/public_html/.htaccess: Expected </IfModule> before end of configuration
    [Wed Oct 11 19:44:15.465143 2017] [core:alert] [pid 30107] [client 130.245.192.0:19889] /var/www/html/website/public_html/.htaccess: Expected </IfModule> before end of configuration
```

The problem was with the .htaccess file in /public_html directory as well.